# After adding new UDIDs to provisioning profile, do I need to rebuild the IPA?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an app (adhoc dist.) and uploaded it to Diawi.
Now, I should add new UDIDs. After add them, do I need to recreate or rebuild the IPA and re-upload to Diawi?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you need to export app with new profile, every time you add new device to your account.

Answer (score 8):

An Ad-hoc IPA will only install on the devices listed in the embedded provisioning profile. If you want the app to be able to be installed on additional devices then yes, you need to provide an updated IPA with the updated profile.

Better yet, use TestFlight and avoid all of this hassle.

Comment: Then What is TestFlight? Is it an app or something like Diawi?

Comment: It is a nightmare for adding more than 3 or 4 testers at a time. I have just been through it and invites were showing as sent in TestFlight but several users insisted they didn't receive the invites.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your query may be in two types of accounts

1) If you have an Enterprise Apple Account: No need to add tester UUDI to the account as the app can be released using Universal distribution binary which any device can install using OTA installation method.

2) If you have the developer account: your existing app will have no impact but yes for the new devices to install you have to regenerate the profile as the existing as on store account portal will get Invalid and needs to be updated for New IPA compilation. The old one will not work.

I would always recommend having an Enterprise account for a testing/building app company as Appstore Developer account is better for Distribution on Appstore or small scale company who rarely adds device ID for debugging and testing unless its standalone developer like scenario.

Comment: As an Enterprise account will we able to Distribute app on Appstore?